# Rows have the height of the table instead of fitting to their content

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Here is my code, copied from the [Quick Start](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/quickstart) guide:

```js
//define some sample data
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
 ];

//create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
    ],
    rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
        alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
    },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

When running it here on StackOverflow, it works, but on my machine I get the following:
[image]

Each row has the height of the entire table. However, the [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/layout#height-row) says:

> By default Tabulator will resize the height of a row to fit the contents of its cells.

What am I missing?